# Adding Rails Individual Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I have a CRUD resource defined in my routes.rb file: `resource :user`.

I'm adding a new controller method for the user called `search_places`, which is performed on the user to find other users with the same `place`s. I'm adding a route it.

Right now, I have:

`post '/user/search_place'`, which isn't very DRY. I'm new to Rails and I was reading the Rails routing documentation and figured that I could possibly use

```
resource :user do
  collection do
    post 'search_place'
  end
end
```

Is this considered good practice? I know this works (it passes my rspec route test), but is that how its best done?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add second don't need of first.

Add this:

```
 resources :user do
   collection do
     post 'search_place'
   end
 end
```

Remove this:

```
 resources :user
```

That makes `DRY` :)

Suggestion: Resources name should be defined in plural if u follow rails convention. (i.e) `resources :users`

Comment: Yeah I just replaced it :) So a route `collection` is used for those sort of things I assume?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. I have it in plural. Thank you

Comment: @Darksky ya `resources :users` gives all seven default routes. To add more routes to resources we use `collection` or `member`

Comment: `collection` adds the route to resource itself. For example `new` is a collection route. `member` adds it to a specific instance, which makes `edit` a member route. Think of it as the difference between class methods and instance methods (collection routes and member routes)